# Resource ID#5 PHP MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have this code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

     mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(colname) FROM profits");

 $total = reset (mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

 mysql_close($con);

 echo $total;

 ?>
```

And its outputting an Resource id #5.  Any help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify where you have problems with more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `reset()` like that - if you need a single value, just use `list()`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(colname) FROM profits");
list($total) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

`reset()` does not work as you expect on associative arrays: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38478

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to echo an associative array with `echo $total;`. Instead just echo the first (and probably only based on your query) item.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row[0];
```