# Sum the total of a column and save as a variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, sum

Trying to sum the total of a column and save as a variable.
The query has worked as I have tested it with PHPMyAdmin.  Just struggling to save the figure received from the query into a variable.

```
 $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM tablename");



  mysql_close($con);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286570/resource-id5-php-mysql-error/10286636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(column_name) as soma FROM tablename");

$row= mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sum= $row['soma'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this will work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(column_name) as thesum FROM tablename");
$sum = mysql_result( $result, 0, "thesum");
```

Or even this should work:

```
$sum = mysql_result( $result, 0);
```

Comment: Well this works- to an extent. I insert this and then the rest of the website seems to disappear. Remove the PHP for this query, and were back to normal. Either im going mad and there is a mistake, of which neither me going over and over and a PHP IDE doesn't pick up, I'm completely confused!

Comment: Either turn on error reporting, or find the error in your error logs. Usually a blank page is associated with an error, which is preventing the page from loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "Select SUM(ver) AS ver from tablename";
$sum = mysql_query($sql);
$result= mysql_fetch_object($sum);
echo $result->ver;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM tablename");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it's good practice to test if $result exists or not:

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```